# Cast geometry field as different type on insert?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, spatial

How can I cast or otherwise insert field `geom_one` of type `geometry(MultiLineString,4326)` into field `geom_two` of type `geometry(MultiLineStringZM,4326)`?

When I attempt to insert using `ST_Force_3D(geom_one)`, it produces the following error:

```
ERROR: Column has M dimension but geometry does not
********** Error **********
ERROR: Column has M dimension but geometry does not
------------------------------------------------------------------------

SQL state: 22023
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note:`ST_Force3D()` is used for PostGIS 2.1 and newer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong function,

> `ST_Force3D` Force the geometries into XYZ mode. This is an alias for ST_Force3DZ.

What you want..

> `ST_Force4D` — Force the geometries into XYZM mode.

`MultiLineStringZM` has a `Z` and an `M` dimension. That makes it 4D.